# hash_password not equal hash passwords

Tags: php, hash

I have a sign up form and a login form. I try to save the password during registration with the function hash_password

```
$password = trim(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['inputPassword']));

$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query_create_user = "INSERT INTO users (user_username, user_password, user_email) VALUES  ('$username', '$password_hash', '$email')";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query_create_user);
```

For login, I use also the function password hash.

```
$password = trim(mysqli_escape_string($conn,$_POST['inputPassword']));

$password_hash = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

$query_verify_user = "SELECT user_id, user_username, user_password FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";

if($row['user_username']==$username && $row['user_password']==$password_hash){
Header('Location: ../index.php?page=login');
}
```

$row['user_password']==$password_hash are never the same. During the registration, I had one hash tag. After the registration, I cant get the same hash tag as during the registration. What is the problem?

Comment: please use prepared statements. and use `password_verify` to verify the posted password against the hashed one.

Comment: shouldn't you use `password_verify` for login instead?

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections. Please learn to use [prepared statements](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLinqtCfhKY).

Comment: Applying `mysqli_escape_string` first and then `password_hash` on the result of that afterwards is high-grade nonsense.

Comment: CBrow, why is it nonsense?

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior of password_hash, to check if the entered password was correct, you should use password_verify as stated in the PHP documentation for [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-returnvalues).

Meaning that your code should be something like this

```
$password = $_POST['inputPassword'];

$query_verify_user = "SELECT user_id, user_username, user_password FROM users WHERE user_username = '$username'";

if($row['user_username']==$username && password_verify($password, $row['user_password']){
    header('Location: ../index.php?page=login');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To perform the password verification, use [password-verify](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).  [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) creates a new password hash using a strong one-way hashing algorithm.